# How to make repeated calls to context.bindings in an azure function

Tags: azure-functions

I am using an Azure function (written in javascript) to write various entries to a Cosmos DB and to send emails using Send Grid.  My issue is that I would like to call "context.bindings.outputCosmosDB" and "context.bindings.message" within a foreach loop to create new database entries in my cosmos database and to send emails using sendgrid.  But, when I attempt to do this, only the first context.bindings call is executed.

For example, if my foreach loop runs 5 times to process 5 different items and each processed items calls context.bindings to write to the database and to send an email, an email is only generated for the first processed item and a database entry is only created for the first processed item.

After a lot of headache I now understand that this is happening because the context.bindings calls are being made asynchronously.  But, I am not sure how I fix this problem.

How can I call context.bindings.message (or context.bindings.outputCosmosDB) multiple times and have each call generate an email (or a database entry)?

Answer (score 0):

For the DB, Azure bindings seem to only be called once per function call. Instead of calling the bind method once per iteration (multiple bind method calls), you can try to create an array of row write objects, then call bind method (one bind method call) after iteration loop has ended.